# Wicket - Display same text on multiple places

Tags: java, wicket

I am building my site for the first time with Wicket and I want to create a portal, where the username would be displayed on multiple places (user menu, header, maybe somewhere else on the page..). Wicket apparently doesn't like labels with the same `wicket:id`, because I get:

> The component [Component id = userName] was rendered already. You can render it only once during a render phase.

Is there some other way to display the same dynamic text on different places without creating a new label for each and every one?

Comment: Since in wicket everything is a component with its own id, no can do.

Comment: @Hannes Maybe you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wicket builds the page to render as a hierarchy parallel to the Dom (HTML) tree. Everything inside Wicket is a component with its own id, mapping to an insertion point within the Dom tree. Rendering would not be deterministic, if components with the same id would be reusable (this would result in a math. graph obscuring the hierarchy and, as a graph, would result in cycles).

The simple answer is that you cannot reuse components.

I would not recommend to fiddle with the ids. Just use the OOP way and create a base component that adds/provides the labels.

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't. Best you can do is to subclass a `Label` that will retrieve the username and use this label in multiple places with different wicket:id's. Like this:

```
public class UserNameLabel extends Label{

    public UserNameLabel(String id) {
        super(id, getTheUsernameSomewhereFrom());
    }

}
```

Comment: Even better to create a UsernameModel instead of using String directly. Wicket can reuse a constructed component tree, so you don't have to go through all constructors etc again. To be able to reuse a label, the model value should change, not the component itself,